# Hat is partially clipped on mobile dropdown

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The hat is partially clipped on the mobile dropdown:

[image]

This appears to be caused by `overflow: hidden;` in `primary.css`:

```
[class*="gravatar-wrapper-"] {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If that line is removed, the hat will display correctly.

This can be reproduced on a desktop browser whenever the responsive view comes into play.